# Manga where a man in car accident body swaps with someone who committed suicide

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's about a guy who is bullied so he takes his life, and at the same time (I think) another guy is in a car accident and he ends up in the suicide victims body! He must live his life but he is a different person so the bullies start to call him mad dog!

A childhood friend who knew the guy in the accident recognizes the behavior and suspects that he is in the new body of his bullied classmate!

Answer (score 10):

This might be [*At the End of the Road*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=136353&method=useful)

> After a **car accident**, Taemin finds himself in the body of Siwon, who was a **victim of bullying at school**. No longer a pushover, he starts standing up for himself but then meets Woojin, **an old friend from the past**. Somehow, Woojin immediately picks up Tamin's 'scent' from Siwon. What happened between these two in the past and how will it affect their future?

Found [here, on Baka-Updates Manga](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=136353&method=useful), with links to the [original web-comic](https://www.lezhin.com/ko/comic/end) and an [English translation](https://www.lezhin.com/en/comic/attheend)

It matches the body swapping, the car accident and suicide, and a childhood friend recognising that something's up

Comment: This sounds super interesting even if it's not what the OP wants